# How to merge cells in pandas dataframe to use as headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm making a very simple single row dataframe in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
                  columns=['x', 'y',
                           'Vx', 'Vy', 'V',
                           'ax', 'ay', 'a',
                           'at', 'an', 'r'])
```

and it looks like this

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  x |  y |  Vx|  Vy|  V |  ax|  ay|  a |  at|  an|  r |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|coordin. |     speed    |       acceleration     |rad |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  x |  y |  Vx|  Vy|  V |  ax|  ay|  a |  at|  an|  r |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So I want to use merged cells as headers of some sort. The tricky thing is that as you can see each header covers different number of columns.
What should I do to make my table look like this?

Comment: looks like you want to create a multi-level (multiindex) dataframe. See if this helps [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820017/how-to-create-a-multilevel-dataframe-in-pandas) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181247/how-do-i-create-a-dataframe-with-multi-level-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a DataFrame with multi-level columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181247/how-do-i-create-a-dataframe-with-multi-level-columns)

Comment: @JoeFerndz no, unfortunately. These examples have repeating columns under the headers. In my case, the columns are different, and, most importantly, the number of columns under one header is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you want a multiindex on the columns...

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
                  columns=[['coord','coord',
                  'vel','vel','vel',
                  'acc','acc','acc','acc','acc',
                  'rad'],
                  ['x', 'y',
                  'Vx', 'Vy', 'V',
                  'ax', 'ay', 'a',
                  'at', 'an', 'r']])
```