# Convert a flattened excel to nested json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-json

I am fairly new to this and have spent the entire day reading numerous posts and figuring out how i can convert this flattened excel table to a nested json. Here is an example of the flattened nested table:

```
    {'Sample': {0: '1A',
  1: '1A',
  2: '1A',
  3: '1A',
  4: '1A',
  5: '1A',
  6: '1A',
  7: '2A',
  8: '2A',
  9: '2A',
  10: '2A',
  11: '2A',
  12: '2A',
  13: '2A'},
 'Substance category': {0: 'Additive',
  1: 'Additive',
  2: 'Alkali',
  3: 'Alkali',
  4: 'Alkali',
  5: 'Alkali',
  6: 'Alkali',
  7: 'Additive',
  8: 'Additive',
  9: 'Alkali',
  10: 'Alkali',
  11: 'Alkali',
  12: 'Alkali',
  13: 'Alkali'},
 'Substance': {0: 'Irgafos 168',
  1: 'Alkylphenylphosphate',
  2: 'Calcium',
  3: 'Kalium',
  4: 'Lithium',
  5: 'Magnesium',
  6: 'Natrium',
  7: 'Irgafos 168',
  8: 'Alkylphenylphosphate',
  9: 'Calcium',
  10: 'Kalium',
  11: 'Lithium',
  12: 'Magnesium',
  13: 'Natrium'},
 'Value': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 2,
  3: 2,
  4: 1,
  5: 2,
  6: 3,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 1,
  12: 2,
  13: 3}}
```

This table looks like this
[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMRZ7.png)

I used the following code to get a nested json, which was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490276/13094264).

```
j = (df.groupby(['Sample','Substance category'])
       .apply(lambda x: x[['Substance','Value']].to_dict('records'))
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'Substance'})
       .to_json(orient='records'))
```

I am getting the following json.

```
[
  {
    "Sample": "1A",
    "Substance": [
      {
        "Substance": "Irgafos 168",
        "Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Alkylphenylphosphate",
        "Value": 0
      }
    ],
    "Substance category": "Additive"
  },
  {
    "Sample": "1A",
    "Substance": [
      {
        "Substance": "Calcium",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Kalium",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Lithium",
        "Value": 1
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Magnesium",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Natrium",
        "Value": 3
      }
    ],
    "Substance category": "Alkali"
  },
  {
    "Sample": "2A",
    "Substance": [
      {
        "Substance": "Irgafos 168",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Alkylphenylphosphate",
        "Value": 3
      }
    ],
    "Substance category": "Additive"
  },
  {
    "Sample": "2A",
    "Substance": [
      {
        "Substance": "Calcium",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Kalium",
        "Value": 3
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Lithium",
        "Value": 1
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Magnesium",
        "Value": 2
      },
      {
        "Substance": "Natrium",
        "Value": 3
      }
    ],
    "Substance category": "Alkali"
  }
]
```

However what I actually want is to define an addition level for the 'Substance category'. Despite all my efforts, I just could not figure that out and none of the answers could help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking for. Please try rephrase and formulate your question, to make it more clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please add an expected output.

Comment: +1 for work put into the question.  The table has only 1 level (header), so what are you looking for please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I am fairly new to this, I could not really paste images and file, otherwise I would just shared the original file to help everyone understand the Q. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well creating a multilevel df was not a problem. But when I exported that to a json, it did not maintain the nested structure of the indexes. Anyway, I finally found an answer here. It was just a matter to searching on google with the right keywords [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923685/convert-pandas-multiindex-series-to-json-python)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This would be my process:

- convert the dict to a dataframe.
- writing to 'json' from a dataframe can be done with `to_json()`

so the code looks like this:

```py
#%%
import pandas as pd

d = {'Sample': {0: '1A',
  1: '1A',
  2: '1A',
  3: '1A',
  4: '1A',
  5: '1A',
  6: '1A',
  7: '2A',
  8: '2A',
  9: '2A',
  10: '2A',
  11: '2A',
  12: '2A',
  13: '2A'},
 'Substance category': {0: 'Additive',
  1: 'Additive',
  2: 'Alkali',
  3: 'Alkali',
  4: 'Alkali',
  5: 'Alkali',
  6: 'Alkali',
  7: 'Additive',
  8: 'Additive',
  9: 'Alkali',
  10: 'Alkali',
  11: 'Alkali',
  12: 'Alkali',
  13: 'Alkali'},
 'Substance': {0: 'Irgafos 168',
  1: 'Alkylphenylphosphate',
  2: 'Calcium',
  3: 'Kalium',
  4: 'Lithium',
  5: 'Magnesium',
  6: 'Natrium',
  7: 'Irgafos 168',
  8: 'Alkylphenylphosphate',
  9: 'Calcium',
  10: 'Kalium',
  11: 'Lithium',
  12: 'Magnesium',
  13: 'Natrium'},
 'Value': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 2,
  3: 2,
  4: 1,
  5: 2,
  6: 3,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 2,
  10: 3,
  11: 1,
  12: 2,
  13: 3}}


# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# %%  send to excel
json_path = "C:\\test\\test.json"
df.to_json(json_path)
```

The dataframe (before the json) looks like this:

[image]

You can manipulate the dataframe as you wish from here.

Are you asking to create a multilevel dataframe ? if so, then the final part is answered here:

[How to create a multilevel dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820017/how-to-create-a-multilevel-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Well creating a multilevel df was not a problem. But when I exported that to a json, it did not maintain the nested structure of the indexes. Anyway, I finally found an answer here. It was just a matter to searching on google with the right keywords
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923685/convert-pandas-multiindex-series-to-json-python) @D.L Thank you for your time and comment anyway

Comment: that is a good find. Glad that the problem is solved.